# Get value error with libxml2 sax parser

Tags: c++, sax, libxml2

I'm trying to parse a xml file with libxml2's sax interface. Sometimes it works great, but then i change 2 lines order in the xml (it remains valid of coure) and some value become invalid after parse. I'm using startElementNsSAX2Func for startElement, it has an argument  const xmlChar ** attributes  which stores the attributes of the current element.

At the beginning of my startElement method, i create a simple object to handle attributes
Here is the code of the class:

```
class XMLElementAttributes {
public:
  static const int AttributeArrayWidth = 5;
  static const int LocalNameIndex = 0;
  static const int PrefixIndex = 1;
  static const int URIIndex = 2;
  static const int ValueIndex = 3;
  static const int EndIndex = 4;

  XMLElementAttributes( int nb_attributes, const xmlChar **attributes) :
  nb_attributes(nb_attributes),
  attributes(attributes){
  }

  xmlChar* getLocalName( int index ) const {
    return (xmlChar*)attributes[ AttributeArrayWidth * index + LocalNameIndex];
  }

  xmlChar* getValue( int index ) const{
      return (xmlChar*)std::string(attributes[ AttributeArrayWidth * index + ValueIndex],attributes[ AttributeArrayWidth * index + EndIndex]).c_str(); 
  }

  int getLength() const{
    return nb_attributes;
  }

private:
  int nb_attributes;
  const xmlChar ** attributes;
};
```

(xmlChar is Typedef unsigned char xmlChar)

Then if i need to store the value of an attribute, i clone it with this staic method (I also tried to use libxml2's xmlStrdup, the result is the same):

```
xmlChar* cloneXMLString(const xmlChar* const source) {
    xmlChar* result;
    int len=0;
    std::cout<<"source"<<std::endl;
    while (source[len] != '\0'){
        std::cout<<(void*)&source[len] << ": " << source[len] <<std::endl;
        len++;
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"result, "<<std::endl;
    result = new xmlChar[len+1];
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++){
        result[i] = source[i];
        std::cout<<(void *)&source[i] << ": "<< source[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    result[len] = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

It works in 99%, but sometimes the result at the end contains nothing similar to the source. Here is an example output (the input is abcdef, and \0 terminated):

```
source
0x7fdb7402cde8: a
0x7fdb7402cde9: b
0x7fdb7402cdea: c
0x7fdb7402cdeb: d
0x7fdb7402cdec: e
0x7fdb7402cded: f


result, 
0x7fdb7402cde8: !
0x7fdb7402cde9: 
0x7fdb7402cdea: 
0x7fdb7402cdeb: 
0x7fdb7402cdec: x
0x7fdb7402cded:
```

I call it this way:

```
xmlChar* value = cloneXMLString(attributes.getValue(index));
```

So while the address of the source didn't changed, it's value did. The parsing of the xml file continues without any problem, the next values after cloneing become valid again.

The error is always at the same element and argument, if the xml file didn't changed. If i change something little in the xml, for example:

```
<somenodes a="arg1" b="arg2">
  <node c="abc" d="def" />
  <node c="ghi" d="jkl" />
</somenodes>
```

to

```
<somenodes a="arg1" b="arg2">
  <node c="ghi" d="jkl" />
  <node c="abc" d="def" />
</somenodes>
```

the error appears somewhere else, or it's disappear and the parseing works fine. What could cause this?

Edit:

My start element method:

```
void MyParser::startElement( void * ctx,
        const xmlChar * localName,
        const xmlChar * prefix,
        const xmlChar * URI,
        int nb_namespaces,
        const xmlChar ** namespaces,
        int nb_attributes,
        int nb_defaulted,
        const xmlChar ** attrs ){

    XMLElementAttributes attributes ( nb_attributes, attrs );

    switch ( state ) {
    case Somestate:
       if ( xmlStrcmp( localName, StrN("SomeName").xmlCharForm() ) == 0) {
         someVar = new SomeObject(attributes);
       } 
    break;

    ...

    }
}
```

StrN creates xmlChar from char*. someVar is a staic field in MyParser class (startElement is also static). In the constructor of SomeObject i try to get the values of attributes like this:

```
class SomeObject {
    public:
    SomeObject( XMLElementAttributes &attributes){
        for (int i=0; i< attributes.getLength(); i++) {
            xmlChar* name = attributes.getLocalName(i);
            if ( xmlStrcmp( name, StrN("somename").xmlCharForm()) == 0 ) {
                somename = cloneXMLString(attributes.getValue(i));
            }
            ...
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that source is not pointing to valid memory. This could be because the memory has already been freed, or it could be because it was pointing to stack memory declared in a function that has already been exitted.

Such memory may be overwritten in an unpredictable way, which is what you are seeing here.

Would need to see more context, particularly how you call `cloneXMLString` and where the memory you pass to this function originates, for a more detailed answer.